# How can I connect Ariba with Python? I'm looking to read documents off Ariba in Python and then use Text Analytics on them

Tags: python, sap-ariba

As part of a Text Analytics use case, I need to read files from Ariba into Python and then use my already ready model to classify them. However, I am not able to find an API that connects Ariba with Python, anywhere online.

Comment: Some update about this topic? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this and the variable here are what documents are we talking about.

### Ariba Integration Toolkit [AITK]

- You need to configure [Integration Toolkit](https://help.sap.com/viewer/d066a90ef618101499ccd55dc3c29025/2006/en-US/d06ce19af6181014ae28e529abace9ce.html) in order to extract data from Ariba.
- To achieve this, find a customer realm and check if AITK is enabled. If yes, you will need to contact the owner of the custeomer realm to know the 'Shared Secret'.
- **By all means refrain from resetting the AITK password without contacting the administrator.** This could break you existing integrations if not done right.
- Well, after you know the 'Shared Secret', extract a dump of documents that you are most interested in. E.g: Contracts and Purchase Orders [POs].
- Until this point you will not make use your Python language as AITK itself comes with several wrapper code snippets for both UNIX and Windows platforms.
- After extracting the data dump or file attachment dump you can perform text analysis.
- I will talk about two usecase here -
- Use case 1: Getting PO data and analyzing the PO Title, line items details and comments etc. using your Python Text Analytics. You have structured text coming from Ariba already.
- Use case 2: You extract a contract attachment which is a PDF document. In this case you will use Python OCR to extract text from such PDF document and then use text analytics.

### Web Services

- Next up, you may use the OOTB [WebServices](https://help.sap.com/viewer/f4204795aea64e909c53dc85a8030fdc/Cloud/en-US/7d75a46dddef477590d76bc4daebe194.html) to export data from Ariba.
- Kindly note that WebServices don't have the same level of support to export attachments from Ariba as AITK. Thus AITK scores better in this area.
- To call Web Services, your client application can be a Python application with API libraries on the top of it.
- Remember this is **SOAP Protocol**

### APIs

- **Ariba opened up APIs only in the last couple of years**
- All the fancy stuff you would expect from [APIs](https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/ARIBA_APIS/cloud/en-US) is already there and being constantly improved.
- The process to get up and running is to request API, get your Customer Admin to approve it and then Ariba company reps to approve it.
- Due to the lifecycle of approvals inolved before you can start building your client applications, it is better to assess your needs and find the best-fit API. There are a lot of them :)
- Remember this is **REST API**
- You can call these APIs using cURL and of course, your Python programs with HTTP request libraries.